# Checking all conditions in a logical disjunction

Tags: java, standards

I found the question in this line of code. Ignore the fact that this code does not make sense:

```
if (object != null || object.someMethod()) object.doSomething();
```

First I was thinking that this code will throw `NullPointerException` if object is null. But, this is a logical disjunction and if one of the conditions is true the whole condition is true. So the compiler doesn't checks the second condition and doesn't throws `NullPointerException`.

Is this Java Standard behavior or implementation specific? If the second case is true than this code is not secure.

Comment: the given code **will** throw `NullPointerException` if object is `null`: it should be `&&` to prevent that

Answer (score 2):

When object is not null, short-circuit evaluation occurs, and `object.someMethod()` is never called.

When object is null, this expression should throw a NullPointerException when `object.someMethod()` is evaluated.

This is not a particularly useful condition. Consider whether && was intended instead of ||.

Answer (score 2):

the `||` is defined by Java to be a short-circuit operator. So if the first condition is `true` it does not evaluate the second condition. This is distinct from the `|` operator which is NOT short-circuit. The reliance on short-circuit operators is VERY common practice when coding Java.

That said, `Marco's` comment is totally correct. You are using the `||` operator where you should probably be using the `&&` operator. Same short-circuit rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

**It is Java standard behaviour**. Logical OR (`||`) is a "short-circuit" operator meaning it only evaluates what it needs to, to determine whether the entire condition is true or not. If you want to force evaluation of each guard use `|`.

Answer (score 0):

`someMethod` could be a static method that returns true even though the object does not exist. Compiler should warn you.